# How to replace numbers with dates or remove rows with numbers from data frame?

Tags: r

I have data frame like this:

```
[701] "38760"      "38788"      "38819"      "38849"      "38880"      "38910"      "38941"     
[708] "38972"      "39002"      "39033"      "39063"      "12/13/2006" "12/14/2006" "12/15/2006"
[715] "12/16/2006" "12/17/2006" "12/18/2006" "12/19/2006" "12/20/2006" "12/21/2006" "12/22/2006"
[722] "12/23/2006" "12/24/2006" "12/25/2006" "12/26/2006" "12/27/2006" "12/28/2006" "12/29/2006"
[729] "12/30/2006" "12/31/2006"
```

and I would like to have only dates (replacing or removing numbers). Anyone know some reasonable quick way to do this?

Comment: When you say replace numbers, can you show the expected output

Comment: I my xls file I have only dates. When I load this file in R I have got something like this and I do not know why. I do not know what dates to replace it with. So I think I will just remove it. Do you know how? Remove rows with numbers.

Comment: e.g. "38760" can be parsed i.e. `library(parsedate); parse_date("38760")
[1] "2021-12-06 12:39:25 UTC"`  I just wanted to know what you expect as date though

Comment: i..e if you do `parse_date(dates)` on the column of 'dates', it should work for all those formats

Comment: I wanted dates just from 2005 and 2006, I will try your way

Comment: Without knowing what your expected dates for those 701:708, it is not easy to specify the `origin`

Comment: If you have excel dates, perhaps, those numeric values would be based on 1899 origin i.e. `openxlsx::convertToDate(38760)#
[1] "2006-02-12"` or in `base R` i.e. `as.Date(38760, origin = '1899-12-30')
[1] "2006-02-12"`

Comment: Okay, but it is just for one number, I want to do this for all data frame

Comment: This is not a data.frame. Looks like a character vector to me. Please clarify what is your data and the desired output

Comment: @paDU you may check the soluiton posted below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that we have a 'dates' column in the `data.frame` which includes only two formats - 1) `%m/%d/%Y` and 2) numeric values - then we apply the `as.Date` with the format `%m/%d/%Y` on the whole 'dates'.  If the values are numeric, it will return `NA`, which we do separately and update in `base R`

```
dates1 <- with(df1, as.Date(dates, format = "%m/%d/%Y"))
dates1[is.na(dates1)] <- with(df1, as.Date(as.integer(dates[is.na(dates1)]), 
       origin = "1899-12-30"))
df1$dates <- dates1
```

-output

```
> df1$dates
 [1] "2006-02-12" "2006-03-12" "2006-04-12" "2006-05-12" "2006-06-12" "2006-07-12" "2006-08-12" "2006-09-12" "2006-10-12" "2006-11-12" "2006-12-12" "2006-12-13"
[13] "2006-12-14" "2006-12-15" "2006-12-16" "2006-12-17" "2006-12-18" "2006-12-19" "2006-12-20" "2006-12-21" "2006-12-22" "2006-12-23" "2006-12-24" "2006-12-25"
[25] "2006-12-26" "2006-12-27" "2006-12-28" "2006-12-29" "2006-12-30" "2006-12-31"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(dates = c("38760", "38788", "38819", "38849", 
"38880", "38910", "38941", "38972", "39002", "39033", "39063", 
"12/13/2006", "12/14/2006", "12/15/2006", "12/16/2006", "12/17/2006", 
"12/18/2006", "12/19/2006", "12/20/2006", "12/21/2006", "12/22/2006", 
"12/23/2006", "12/24/2006", "12/25/2006", "12/26/2006", "12/27/2006", 
"12/28/2006", "12/29/2006", "12/30/2006", "12/31/2006")),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-30L))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Work like I wanted! :)

Answer (score 2):

I assume it is a `Excel` date. So now you can use the `origin` argument of `as.Date` which December 30, 1899.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(date = as.Date(date, origin = "1899-12-30"))
```

```
       date Przedmiescie Centrum
1 2005-01-01            0       0
2 2005-02-01            0       0
3 2005-03-01            0       0
4 2005-04-01            0       0
5 2005-05-01            0       2
6 2005-06-01            0       0
```

data:

```
structure(list(date = c(38353L, 38384L, 38412L, 38443L, 38473L, 
38504L), Przedmiescie = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Centrum = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```